# How does AWS Kinesis throttle write throughput?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-kpl

AWS Kinesis has a fairly low write throughput of 1000 writes/sec and 1MB/writes-sec.  How does Kinesis enforce this limit?  If I were to try to do 1500 writes in a second, would the extra 500 writes be placed into some sort of queue or would they simply fail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it simply fails and throws an exception.

> An unsuccessfully processed record includes ErrorCode and ErrorMessage values. ErrorCode reflects the type of error and can be one of the following values: ProvisionedThroughputExceededException or InternalFailure. ErrorMessage provides more detailed information about the ProvisionedThroughputExceededException exception including the account ID, stream name, and shard ID of the record that was throttled. For more information about partially successful responses, see Adding Multiple Records with PutRecords in the Amazon Kinesis Data Streams Developer Guide.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html

How the rate limiting is done

> Rate Limiting
>   The KPL includes a rate limiting feature, which limits per-shard throughput sent from a single producer. Rate limiting is implemented using a token bucket algorithm with separate buckets for both Kinesis Data Streams records and bytes. Each successful write to an Kinesis data stream adds a token (or multiple tokens) to each bucket, up to a certain threshold. This threshold is configurable but by default is set 50% higher than the actual shard limit, to allow shard saturation from a single producer.
>
> You can lower this limit to reduce spamming due to excessive retries. However, the best practice is for each producer is to retry for maximum throughput aggressively and to handle any resulting throttling determined as excessive by expanding the capacity of the stream and implementing an appropriate partition key strategy.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-producer-adv-retries-rate-limiting.html

Answer (score 4):

This depends on the way that you're writing the data.

If you're using [PutRecord](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecord.html) then any request that exceeds the limit will fail with `ProvisionedThroughputExceededException` and you'll have to retry the request. However, since round-trip times for a single request are on the order of 20-30 ms, you'll need to have a large number of clients to get throttled.

The [PutRecords](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesis/latest/APIReference/API_PutRecords.html) call has a much higher likelihood of being throttled, because you can send up to 500 records in a single request. And if it's throttled, the throttling may affect the entire request or individual records within the request (this could happen if one shard accepts records but another doesn't).

To deal with this, you need to examine the `Records` list from the `PutRecords` response. This array corresponds exactly with the `Records` list from the request, but contains `PutRecordsResultEntry` values.

If an entry has a `SequenceNumber` then you're OK: that record was written to a shard. If, however, it has an `ErrorCode` then you need to copy the record from the request and re-send it (assuming that the error code is throughput exceeded; you could also try resending if it's internal error, but that may not work).

You will need to loop, calling `PutRecords` until the response doesn't have any unsent messages.

Beware that, due to the possibility of individual records being throttled and resent, you can't guarantee the order that records will appear on a shard (they are stored in the shard in the order that they were received).